# When dual booting with Windows, should I switch GRUB or UEFI priorities?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I am reconfiguring my dual boot system, and learning more about UEFI leads me to wonder whether I have been doing things properly.

Right now my UEFI priorities are set to boot GRUB, and if I want to use Windows I get GRUB to chain load (I think that’s the right term?) to Windows Boot Manager.  Is there any reason (other than convenience) to prefer this way, as opposed to opening up UEFI/BIOS settings and overriding the boot priority to boot directly to Windows Boot Manager?

Comment: I would not _change_ how you currently do it in case something is set up to work with one method or the other, and changing it may break that. "If it is not broken, do not fix it!" But if you are certain it will work either way, there is no objective reason to choose one method over another. Chose the method you prefer for yourself.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. So if Windows update turns fast start up on, or it gets corrupted needing chkdsk, you have to use UEFI to directly boot into Windows & probably its repair console. Best to also have Windows repair/recovery disk.  It may depend just on which system you use the most and which is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is likely to be opinion-based.  But frankly: no, no reason at all.

Since the rise the UEFI the usefulness of a grub menu has been reduced.  I did exactly what you described for years.  Most BIOS have a boot menu (often <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>) separate to the main bios menu (often <kbd>F1</kbd>,<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd>).  So when I did this I just hit F10 if I wanted a different OS to the default.

Grub still has some usefulness, being able to select an old Kernel or change boot params before boot is still useful.  But switching between entire OS is less useful now.

Answer (score 0):

Even for today's systems BIOS flash ROMs support only a limited number of rewrites, so if you constantly switch OS'es you may kill your BIOS ROM. GRUB stores its configuration on the disk, so it's safe to use.

Comment: You will probably wear out your F12 key before that happens. Besides, modern disks use flash, too.